# Rails Project on Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, docker, docker-compose

I use Docker to run the Rails Project,but it can't run never,I'm very sad.
This is the start_up.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

and the docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
redis:
 image: daocloud.io/daocloud/dao-redis:master-init
 environment:
  - REDIS_PASS=**None**
 ports:
   - "6379:6379"
 web:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile_dev
  environment:
   - REDIS_HOST=redis
  command: /bin/bash docker_web_run.dev.sh
  volumes:
    - /Users/skio_boss:/rails_app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    - "10022:22"
  links:
    - redis
```

and the Dockerfile_dev:

```
FROM daocloud.io/skio_dep/rails_4.2.6:v1_onbuild

#set ssh password
RUN echo "root:123456" | chpasswd

ENV RACK_ENV development
# redis
ENV REDIS_HOST redis

# CMD sh docker_web_run.dev.sh
```

and the docker_web_run.dev.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
/usr/sbin/sshd
/etc/init.d/cron start
bundle exec rake db:migrate

#whenever -w
#echo `bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`
passenger start --environment development --port 3000
```

## Then the environment is that:

ubuntu 16.04, Docker version 1.12.1
when I run : $ ./start_up.sh
the container is build successful

```
Successfully built 628dbf7ff242
Creating skioboss_redis_1
Creating skioboss_web_1
Attaching to skioboss_redis_1, skioboss_web_1
```

the skioboss_web_1 don't run and the error is :

```
web_1    | /bin/bash: docker_web_run.dev.sh: No such file or directory
skioboss_web_1 exited with code 127
```

when I run the skioboss_web_1 with my hand instead of the docker_web_run.dev.sh script, the script file is there (/rails_app/docker_web_run.dev.sh )
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to slove the problem:
the volumes, I don't care of it, it's good when i make a link to the /Users directory.
**volumes:
    - /Users/skio_boss:/rails_app**